Как сменить исчезновение изменением размера?
Могу ли я как нибудь заставить его не исчезать и проявляться , а изменять размер?


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(300);

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(300, redirectPage);
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoBlack'; 
    src: url(./fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf); 
}

    body{
        margin: 0;
        background-image: url(./img/Frame\ 1\(2\).png);
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .lr{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #r{
        background-image: url(./img/09-1.png);
        background-size: cover;
        width: 30%;
        background-position: center;
        aspect-ratio: 1/1;
        
    }
    #l{
        height: 50%;
        width: 45%;
    }
    .btnstu{
        background-color: #BFFFD1;
        opacity: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 75px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: RobotoBlack;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .btnstd{
        background-color: #97FFB4;
        opacity: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 75px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: RobotoBlack;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    a{
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 75px;
        font-style: initial;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .sctex{
        font-size: 0px;
    }
    .scimg{
        width: 0;
    }
    .screensaver {
        position: absolute;
      }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>start</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="screensaver">
        <div class="sctex">Пожалуйста, поверните ваш девайс</div>
        <div class="scimg"></div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="lr" id="l">
            <a href="./menu.html" class="transition"><div class="btnstu">НАЧАТЬ</div></a>
            <a href="./info.html" class="transition"><div class="btnstd">ИНФОРМАЦИЯ</div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="lr" id="r"></div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Можно применять jquery анимацию для любых элементов и для любых параметров этого элемента


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    animateBody();      

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        
        animateBody(redirectPage);        
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        alert(111)
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
    
    function animateBody(callback) {      
       $("body").animate({          
          width: "toggle",
          height: "toggle"
       }, 1000, function() {
          if (callback)
            callback();
       });
    }
});
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoBlack'; 
    src: url(./fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf); 
}

    body{
        margin: 0;
        background-image: url(./img/Frame\ 1\(2\).png);
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .lr{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #r{
        background-image: url(./img/09-1.png);
        background-size: cover;
        width: 30%;
        background-position: center;
        aspect-ratio: 1/1;
        
    }
    #l{
        height: 50%;
        width: 45%;
    }
    .btnstu{
        background-color: #BFFFD1;
        opacity: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 75px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: RobotoBlack;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .btnstd{
        background-color: #97FFB4;
        opacity: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 75px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: RobotoBlack;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    a{
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 75px;
        font-style: initial;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .sctex{
        font-size: 0px;
    }
    .scimg{
        width: 0;
    }
    .screensaver {
        position: absolute;
      }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>start</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="screensaver">
        <div class="sctex">Пожалуйста, поверните ваш девайс</div>
        <div class="scimg"></div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="lr" id="l">
            <a href="./menu.html" class="transition"><div class="btnstu">НАЧАТЬ</div></a>
            <a href="./info.html" class="transition"><div class="btnstd">ИНФОРМАЦИЯ</div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="lr" id="r"></div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



И ещё можно это сделать через стили CSS и просто навешивать эти классы в коде или убирать их. Как пример:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1577345/191482
